# How to make textField validation code more compact and readable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am writing code for textField validation. The textField simply does not allow the user to write age other than 16..<80. I have written the code below and I feel it is poor in quality. Your suggestions to make below code more readable will be really helpful.

Setup:

Create textField and make a delegate to self.

```
extension UserProfileViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let numberFiltered = string.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted).joined(separator: "")

        guard string == numberFiltered, range.location < 2 else {
            return false
        }

        if range.location==0, string.intValue == 0 {
            return false
        }

        guard let textFieldValue = textField.text?.intValue, let currentValue = string.intValue else {
            return true
        }

        let totalValue = textFieldValue*10 + currentValue

        switch totalValue {
        case 16..<80:
            return true
        default:
            textField.text = ""
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use some comments at the top to explain what's going on w/ the numberFiltered portion...esp if you're banking on people glancing at it to chime in. Additionally, you may want to break. out the code inside the delegate method and pass whatever parameters you need to return a Bool for it. Lastly, `option + command + /` and fill in the parameters of your method to explain what they're doing. It's super easy to document code with that keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Jigar, you can set keyboard type to numbers from your storyboard and can validate for the range only. Also disable the paste option for that text field.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your comment, what I believe is code speaks louder and clear than any documentation, but yeh I'll add documentation as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you are doing is unnecessary. Just calculate what the new string would be, attempt to convert to an `Int`, and check the range.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text!
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: oldText)!, with: string)
    if let num = Int(newText), num >= 16 && num < 70 {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

FYI - Both uses of `!` here are safe. `UITextField text` will never return `nil` and unless there is a serious bug in iOS, the range will be valid.

Comment: Ah, of course. Let's say you want to enter 30. When you type the `3`, it fails because 3 is not between 16 and 70. You should only validate ensure that the entered text is between 1 and 70 in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and use `textFieldShouldEndEditing` to ensure it is between 16 and 70.